# Sort using custom pattern

Tags: sort

Is there a way to output file's contents using custom patterns?

For instance, having a file `myfile` with following contents:

```
a
d
b
c
```

..how would one sort it using following pattern: print lines starting with "b" first, then print lines starting with "d" and then print lines in normal alphabetical order, so expected output is:

```
b
d
a
c
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use something more than just the `sort` command. First `grep` the `b` lines, then the `d` lines and then sort anything without the `b` or `d` at the end of that.

```
grep '^b' myfile > outfile
grep '^d' myfile >> outfile
grep -v '^b' myfile | grep -v '^d' | sort >> outfile
cat outfile
```

will result in:

```
b
d
a
c
```

This is assuming that the lines start with the 'pattern' `b` and `d` if that is the **whole** pattern or something inside the line you can leave out the caret (`^`)

A one-line equivalent would be:

```
(grep '^b' myfile ; grep '^d' myfile ; grep -v '^b' myfile | grep -v '^d' | sort)
```

Answer (score 14):

When you need data to be sorted beyond `sort`'s capability, a common approach is to pre-process the data to prepend a sort key, then sort, and finally remove the extra sort key. For example, here, add a `0` if a line starts with `b`, a `1` if a line starts with `d`, and a `2` otherwise.

```
sed -e 's/^b/0&/' -e t -e 's/^d/1&/' -e 't' -e 's/^/2/' |
sort |
sed 's/^.//'
```

Note that this sorts all the `b` and `d` lines. If you want these lines in the original order, then the easiest approach is to [split off the lines that you want to leave unsorted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75498/sort-using-custom-pattern/75499#75499). You can, however, work the original line into a sort key with `nl` — but here it's more complicated. (Replace `\t` by a literal tab character throughout if your sed doesn't understand that syntax.)

```
nl -ba -nln |
sed 's/^[0-9]* *\t\([bd]\)/\1\t&/; t; s/^[0-9]* *\t/z\t0\t/' |
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n |
sed 's/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t//'
```

Alternatively, use a language such as Perl, Python or Ruby that lets you easily specify a custom sort function.

```
perl -e 'print sort {($b =~ /^[bd]/) - ($a =~ /^[bd]/) ||
                     $a cmp $b} <>'
python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write(sorted(sys.stdin.readlines(), key=lambda s: (0 if s[0]=="b" else 1 if s[0]=="d" else 2), s))'
```

or if you want to leave the `b` and `d` lines in the original order:

```
perl -e 'while (<>) {push @{/^b/ ? \@b : /^d/ ? \@d : \@other}, $_}
         print @b, @d, sort @other'
python -c 'import sys
b = []; d = []; other = []
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    if line[0]=="b": b += line
    elif line[0]=="d": d += line
    else: other += line
other.sort()
sys.stdout.writelines(b); sys.stdout.writelines(d); sys.stdout.writelines(other)'
```

Comment: The idea of pre-processing sounds promising, however neither of your sed examples really work for me

Comment: The second sed example was nonsense and I've fixed it, but the first works for me. What's wrong with it?

Comment: With first example I get an error when `t;` is inside, when I replace `t` with `\t`, literal tab or take it off I get following output: `0b\n 1d\n a\n c\n` which is close but `b` and `d` are left with integers

Comment: @Sergey, you must have copied the code wrong.  The first sed example is an excellent and efficient solution to this problem.  Just copy and paste the first example into your terminal, type in the lines a, b, c, d, and then control-d to see output.  It would help if you can tell us the content of the error message.  It sounds like you have a missing quote or other syntax.

Comment: @RobertL So I figured it out. I'm getting `sed: 1: "s/^b/0&/; t; s/^d/1&/;  ...": undefined label '; s/^d/1&/; t; s/^/2/'` on BSD version of SED (used by default on FreeBSD and OS X), however it indeed works perfectly fine on GNU SED 4.2.2

Comment: @Sergey Good info.  This modified version works on my FreeBSD:  `sed -e 's/^b/0&/; t' -e 's/^d/1&/; t' -e 's/^/2/'`  (on FreeBSD, `sed` commands `:label`, `t`, and `b` don't work with semi-colon separators)

Answer (score 4):

One way of solving this using `awk` would be:

```
sort myfile | awk '$0 ~ /^b/ || $0 ~ /^d/ {print} $0 !~ /^b/ && $0 !~ /^d/ { a[f++] = $0 } END { for (word = 0; word < f; word++) { print a[word] } }'
```

Comment: @Anthon Yes, according to my results AWK method runs in average 2 times faster. Check out this gist for details: https://gist.github.com/sergeylukin/5564524

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file | tr bd '\1\2' | LANG=C sort | tr '\1\2' bd
```

Where the intermediary contents are: (printing CrtA, CrtB as `Ⓐ`, `Ⓑ`)

```
file  | tr-1  | sort  | tr-2
------------------------------
cat     cat     Ⓐat     bat
bed     ⒶeⒷ     ⒶeⒷ     bed
fog     fog     Ⓑay     day
dog     Ⓑog     Ⓑog     dog
egg     egg     cat     cat
day     Ⓑay     egg     egg
kin     kin     fog     fog
lay     lay     get     get
in      in      in      in
bat     Ⓐat     kin     kin
get     get     lay     lay
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to grep solution, if have file records and you want to preserve an order you can use **xargs** where you call **grep**.
Let's say you have file containing some data (custom_sort.txt):

```
ccc
aaa
xxx
nnn
```

And you want to search sorted grep file which contains additional information (sorted-data.txt):

```
aaa info
bbb test
ccc warn
...
mmm test
nnn info
...
xxx warn
```

If you simply grep through you will receive following output:

```
aaa info
ccc warn
nnn info
xxx warn
```

To get data ordered like in original file you need to:

```
cat custom_sort.txt | xargs -l1 -I KEY grep KEY sorted-data.txt
```

The output will be:

```
ccc warn
xxx warn
aaa info
nnn info
```