# How to list files named like XXXmmyy.dat in natural chronological order?

Tags: shell-script, ls, sort

I use a Mac OS X (V10.9.5) and work in the X11 window, and I often need to deal with thousands of files named like `XXXmmyy.dat`, where `XXX` is a 3-letter acronym of a place, `mm` is the 2-digit month, and the `yy` is the 2-digit year.

This format is a legacy from last century and continues to be used in this case. And I am not in a position to rename these files.

Could anyone devise an `ls` (UNIX command for listing) command that would list the above mentioned files in natural chronological order (as if the files are named like `XXXyyyymm.dat` where `yyyy` is the 4-digit year, and `mm` is the 2-digit month)?

Comment: Maybe related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75498/sort-using-custom-pattern

Comment: The last sentence is ambiguous.  It states that the files should be listed chronologically, but the example implies that they would be sorted first by location (XXX) and then by date (which is what you would get from `ls` if the files were named in the format XXXyyyymm.dat).

Answer (score 2):

To sort chronologically:

```
ls *.dat | sort -k 1.6,1.7 -k 1.4,1.5
```

To sort by location, and then chronologically:

```
ls *.dat | sort -k 1.1,1.3 -k 1.6,1.7 -k 1.4,1.5
```

The [`sort` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sort.1.html) explains how `-k POS1,POS2` works:

> `-k`, `--key=POS1`[`,POS2`]
>    start a key at `POS1`, end it at `POS2` (origin 1)
>
> `POS`  is  `F[.C][OPTS]`, where `F` is the field number and `C` the character position in the field.  `OPTS` is one or more single-letter ordering options, which override global ordering options for that key.  If no key is given, use the entire line as the key.

Comment: On Mac OS X it is possible to apply filename `NUL` OCD, but unfortunately not with `ls`: `printf '%s\0' *.dat | sort -z -k BLAH BLAH BLAH | tr '\0' '\n'`. If we add some guess to the asker's intent, i.e. to have a sorted file list, this may still be acceptable.

Comment: When a question, such as this one, specifies a specific file name format, I don't think it's worth the extra code and associated obfuscation that comes with protecting against newlines embedded in filenames.  People who work IT,  run servers, do backups, etc. know their inputs and outputs and don't have time to protect against problems which will never happen.  Your code is excellent for its intended purpose, and will be valuable in an app, for example, that takes file names from unknown sources, such as random unknown users dragging and dropping user named files, into the app.

Comment: That's why I said *OCD* :)

Comment: OCD? You or me?  :-)