# How do I customize character sort order?

Tags: linux, ls, sort

How can I set the character order/precedence of characters in Linux?

I am currently using the command to test this as follows:

```
ls -al --group-directories-first
```

Say I have the following files:

```
a
b
c
A
B
C
.a
.b
.c
.A
.B
.C
```

The default output from ls is this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:18 a
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:55 .a
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:18 A
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:55 .A
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:18 b
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:55 .b
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:18 B
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:55 .B
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:18 c
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:55 .c
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:18 C
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:55 .C
```

The output order I want:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:55 .A
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:55 .a
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:55 .B
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:55 .b
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:55 .C
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:55 .c
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:18 A
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:18 a
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:18 B
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:18 b
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:18 C
-rw-r--r--  1 username  username     0 Jan 11 07:18 c
```

Things I have tried in `.bashrc`:

```
export LC_ALL="C"               #Did not work
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" #Did not work
export LC_LANG="C"              #Did not work
export LC_COLLATE="C"           #Did not work
```

So, how would I make my own custom character order/precedence?

Thanks

Comment: This is really really hard. I'm trying to find a reference to another question where we discussed this kind of thing in great detail. From memory my conclusion would be that your custom sort order is hard enough to do right that it might as well be impossible. If you can satisfy yourself with either the C locale or your own country one that would be much "better".

Comment: Here we are - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/328300/100397

Comment: [How to create a new system locale](http://askubuntu.com/questions/653008/how-to-create-a-new-system-locale). It's for Ubuntu, but the same principles should apply on many Linux systems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into this further.

Comment: is the following output acceptable? [test@test test]$ ls -Ar|sort -t . -k2
a
A
b
c
d
.A
.b
.B
.C
.D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that `sort` command could provide some help.

`-t, --field-separator=SEP`

use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition

`-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]`

start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)

```
ls -lAr|sort -t . -k2
-rw-r--r-- 1 CRM CCRM 0 Jan 20 09:35 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 CRM CCRM 0 Jan 20 09:35 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 CRM CCRM 0 Jan 20 09:36 c
-rw-r--r-- 1 CRM CCRM 0 Jan 20 09:36 d
-rw-r--r-- 1 CRM CCRM 0 Jan 20 09:38 A
-rw-r--r-- 1 CRM CCRM 0 Jan 20 10:34 .a
-rw-r--r-- 1 CRM CCRM 0 Jan 20 09:36 .A
-rw-r--r-- 1 CRM CCRM 0 Jan 20 09:38 .b
-rw-r--r-- 1 CRM CCRM 0 Jan 20 09:36 .B
-rw-r--r-- 1 CRM CCRM 0 Jan 20 09:36 .C
-rw-r--r-- 1 CRM CCRM 0 Jan 20 09:36 .D
```

Comment: Thank you! This didn't sort it quite how I wanted, but it's the closest answer. I eventually gave up on this, and use Windows with the Linux sub-system built in for most of the work now.

Answer (score 1):

The km_KH locale sorts close to what you asked for albeit with lower case before upper case.  The km_KH locale was included in the standard install of Centos 7.  So it's a fair guess it might be available on other distros, perhaps via extra packages in the repositories.

You can put this alias definition in your .bashrc:

```
 $ alias l='LC_COLLATE=km_KH ls -lA'
 $ touch a b c A B C .a .b .c .A .B .C
 $ l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 2020-11-08 18:01 .a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 2020-11-08 18:01 .A
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 2020-11-08 18:01 .b
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 2020-11-08 18:01 .B
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 2020-11-08 18:01 .c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 2020-11-08 18:01 .C
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 2020-11-08 18:01 a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 2020-11-08 18:01 A
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 2020-11-08 18:01 b
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 2020-11-08 18:01 B
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 2020-11-08 18:01 c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 2020-11-08 18:01 C
```

The ar_SA locale also sorts close to what you asked for albeit with the dotfiles last:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 Nov  8 18:33 A
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 Nov  8 18:33 a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 Nov  8 18:33 B
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 Nov  8 18:33 b
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 Nov  8 18:33 C
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 Nov  8 18:33 c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 Nov  8 18:33 .A
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 Nov  8 18:33 .a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 Nov  8 18:33 .B
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 Nov  8 18:33 .b
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 Nov  8 18:33 .C
-rw-rw-r-- 1 g greg 0 Nov  8 18:33 .c
```

Here's a simple loop to see how each installed locale sorts the current directory:

```
for a in $(locale -a);do echo $a;LC_COLLATE=$a ls -Al;done|&less
```

Or you can employ some utility tricks, like this one:  [Sort using custom pattern](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75498/sort-using-custom-pattern)

The sort and join answer here is fascinating:  http://superuser.com/questions/489275/how-to-do-custom-sorting-using-unix-sort

Or you can bite the bullet and define your own locale, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/653008/how-to-create-a-new-system-locale