# How do I count the occurrences in a list, and then sort by descending occurrence?

Tags: sort, uniq

I have a list with 1601 lines, where on each line, I am interested in counting the # of times different values appear for fields 5.

Here's what I have so far:

```
awk '{print$5}' FILE  | sort | uniq -c
```

What this gives me is a list of uniq values, with their respective counts.  But I would like to sort this list.  I've been seeing [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336624/how-do-i-customize-character-sort-order) that discuss keys and values, but it hasn't been clear how I can apply it to my case.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing a `sort -b -n` at the end of the pipeline (as another stage of it):

```
awk '{ print $5 }' FILE  | sort | uniq -c | sort -b -n
```

`sort -b -n` will sort the lines produced by the earlier stages of the pipeline numerically (ignoring leading blanks).  If two lines has the same number at the start, a lexicographical ordering of the lines will be performed.

Comment: what's the way to get it in descending?  This gives ascending.  Tx!

Comment: Ah - just add -r

Answer (score 1):

Just sort again by column. Using -k1 sorts by the first column (occurrences), using -k2 sorts by the second column (values):

```
awk '{print $5}' FILE | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1   # Sort by ascending occurrences
awk '{print $5}' FILE | sort | uniq -c | sort -k2   # Sort by ascending values
```

If you need it in descending order (-r):

```
awk '{print $5}' FILE | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1 -r   # Sort by descending occurrences
awk '{print $5}' FILE | sort | uniq -c | sort -k2 -r   # Sort by descending values
```

Comment: You need to specify a numeric sort to sort numbers correctly.

Comment: Why? I tried it without -n and numbers are sorted correctly: https://paste.ofcode.org/33G3SYVgczZu6eC453tAH4h. This is my sort version:
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.26

Comment: Ah, I see now. `uniq -c` outputs the numbers preceded by spaces, which is why it works.

Comment: the final sort  -k1 gave me a weird result.  The order of the occurrences was 10, 1, 118, 1, 13,16,1, 23...  any idea why?  I get the feeling it doesn't look at it like a numeric value but don't understand why the 1's don't appear together.  Full command line was:  awk '{print$5}' FILE | | sort | uniq -c | sort -k2